# Start Parsing within Nested JSON Object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "uri": {
    "{{firstname}}": "Peter",
    "{{lastname}}": "Griffin",
    "{{age}}": 42
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize it into my Bean:

```
public class Uri {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;

    /* getter and setter */
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "uri" (class com.abc.Uri), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "firstname", "lastname", "age")
```

So I assume, I need to get *into* the property `uri`.

Is there any way, to start parsing directly within the `uri` property?

**Update:**

This is how I read the JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
uri = mapper.readValue(new URL("test2.json"), Uri.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method will not work because you are trying to get the whole json object at once, without getting a specific node at first.

Instead of loading your json with the mapper constructor, get your json in a different way. I would use `URL` and `HTTPURLConnection` to get the json string from the web.

After you have your json string, use this:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
```

Get the json node that `uri` represents, like this:

```
JsonNode uriNode = rootNode.get("uri");
```

And only then send that node to be parsed, like this:

#### Jackson 2.4

```
Uri uri = objectMapper.treeToValue(uriNode, Uri.class);
```

#### Prior to Jackson 2.4

```
Uri uri = objectMapper.readValue(uriNode, Uri.class);
```

Comment: Please see my update. How can I specify the node in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You JSON should be of the format:

```
{
  "uri": {
    "firstname": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Griffin",
    "age": 42,
  }
}
```